# Unable to delete carrierwave image again

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I seem to be having an issue deleting an image in my edit form with carrierwave, I have tried all the things i think there are to do. I would like to be able to remove an image within my edit form

```
<!-- File Upload -->
<%= f.fields_for :animal_images do |build| %>
  <div class="form-group">
  <% if build.object.image? %>

  <%= image_tag build.object.image_url :small_animal_image %>
  <%= build.check_box :remove_image, class: 'form-control' %>

<% else %>  
  <%= build.label :image, 'Upload Images' %><br />
  <%= build.file_field :image, class: 'form-control' %>
<% end %>
 </div>

 <%= build.link_to_remove "Remove this Image" %>

<% end %>
```

I have also tried

```
<%= build.check_box :_destroy, class: 'form-control' %>
```

I have added :remove_image and :_destroy to my permitted params

and also have the correct setup in my model

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :animal_images, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :animal_images, allow_destroy: :true 
end
```

Am i missing anything obvious ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentations](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)

```
If you want to remove the file manually, you can call remove_avatar!, then save the object.
@user.remove_avatar!
@user.save
#=> true
```

So something like this should work: `@animal.remove_animal_images!`

Comment: thanks Joe but how would i apply that to my  situation ?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had a remove image link in the wrong place which seems to have caused the click of the check box not to pass the correct param. This is how the working setup is laid out:

```
<!-- File Upload -->
<%= f.fields_for :animal_images do |build| %>
<div class="form-group">
 <% if build.object.image? %>

  <%= image_tag build.object.image_url :small_animal_image %>
  <%= build.label "Remove Image" %>
  <%= build.check_box :_destroy, class: 'form-control' %>

<% else %>  
 <%= build.label :image, 'Upload Images' %><br />
 <%= build.file_field :image, class: 'form-control' %>
 <%= build.link_to_remove "Remove This Image" %>
<% end %>
</div>
```